# Check that no file is forgotten for the installshield project

Tags: installshield

we actually build an InstallShield project for our application with the functionality to include files dynamic into a component. All files will be taken which are in a specific place.

Because of problems, which are not part of this question, we want to change this to components where we add files explicit to custom separated components.

The question is, is there a best practice for this? We have the small fear that we easily can forget to add files to the component we new created. These can be dll files, .config files, pdfs or just xml.

(We build the installer every night using TFS.)

Comment: Unfortunately InstallShield does not handle "project output" in the expected way, and often ignores necessary files in a project. If you build the file every night, do you also deploy it?

Comment: In our build definition list we have a "nightly" which builds the project normally (without tests this time) and after the build a solution for installshield will be build which takes the files from the drop folder.

Comment: Do you have anything that actually "Installs" the install package? If you are creating it nightly, and you install it nightly, you could compare the target filesystem with the source control repository to see if anything is missing.

Comment: We have automated UI tests which will do this, install and check if everything works, but this then has a delay we don't can accept. And comparing by the source control is a little tricky because the source files are located in several places and not all there will be used in the solution and some files are generated or renamed and all these stuff.  But we have a solution, see my own answer below.  Thansk for your Idea anyway!

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution for the problem.
What we wanted to solve:

1. During the build we want to be informed if files got removed
2. During the build we want to be informed if new files are missing

we solved this by two more or less easy things.

**1. Information if a file is removed**
This is easy sone, we have all files added explicitly, each single file is an own component now, if one file is missing the whole project does not build with the exact error message.

**2. Information for missing files**
For this we wrote a small tool which runs by a prebuild event of the installshield project.
There it opens the *.ism file as an xml file and searches for the "Files" table.
Than it takes all files from the drop folder and looks if all files are in there.

If there are files missing but we don't expect them, like pdb files or test dlls, we have an additional text file we just called "IgnoreList".
The tool skips these files by the check.

Now we are on a very good state to get informed directly on the next morning if the project was able to build or not, and if not what happened, so we can be sure that in the final target application are files are there :-)